What is wrong with my op-amp?

I'm trying to make a signal generator using a 555 timer, that works fine and it produces my desired pulse signal. Now I want another output as a sawtooth signal so I went and added and integrating op-amp to integrate the pulse wave, the problem is that it doesn't work properly and I don't know why. I'm going mad really because I can't see the issue anywhere, the question is that I want a sawtooth output through the mechanism of integration this op-amp provides me, but it doesn't work properly, so I want to know what can I edit in the circuit to make it provide me with the desired output?
EDIT: this is a school project and i need to only use LM741 and a battery to power it, this is the only way of integration that's acceptable, the problem with the circuit so far is the bias of the GND and the non-inv. pins, those are the problem, i need suggestions to how can i bias them correctly to achieve the sawtopoth signal


You may want to consider switching to a more modern opamp, such as LM7301. But I agree that you still need either dualsided supply or to bias the + input.

Reasons not to use a 741 op-amp

maybe use an op-amp to just buffer the 555's ramp voltage?

Oters have suggested an opamp change to 'single sided'. A not quite as old LM324 (quad) / LM358 (dual) will meet your need. Create a "reference groud" with a resistive divider.

due to my prof. instructions, i can only use, battery and LM741, in light of these information from what i can understand the problem is with GND and non-inv. ports of the op-amp, what do you guys suggest i bias them to ?

@AbdullahAhmed this site welcomes questions like this when you show the previous effort, like you did. Please edit you question and add the information that this is a school project and provide all the requirements and constraints you received. If you do this we will be able to give better directions, using the socractic method, as it is usual here.

@devnull i did that just now, thanks for helping me notice this.

@AbdullahAhmed  Please see the addition to my answer. If you use an LM741 you MUST operate the circuit within the voltage ranges that I specify. I explain why.  || Your Prof MAY be specifying an LM741 because he wants to show how much harder it used to belong ago to do things that are now much simpler. OR he may need to be introduced to the cheaper better more avaiable LM324 :-)

its the first option, he said that i would encounter many problems with it and that those problems would lead to a more in-depth understanding of op-amp connections and inner-workings, even though he is right, it is a pain, i solved it and iam going to type how in a another comment to be seen by others who will encounter this problem, i would like though to thank you very much for the effort you provided to help me, you guys helped me immensely, i swear i can't be more grateful and indebted due to your kindness, thank you, really.

You are doing at least two things wrong. 9V is insufficient power supply voltage for the LM741 20V (+/-10V) is the minimum recommended. You are violating the input voltage range which is 3V above the negative rail to 3V below the positive rail. Since you have the negative rail grounded you cannot ground the non-inverting input. This is right in the datasheet, albeit described indirectly as the input voltage range with +/-15V supplies.


To get this to work, give the op-amp bipolar supplies such as +/-12V or +/-15V (ground is the center point between the two supplies) then your circuit will work with the non-inverting input grounded.

firstly thank you for your time and helping me, secondly, if you don't mind i am going to walkthrough the process i will be doing depending on the information you so kindly provided me, i gave the timer a 12v battery, so that makes the output of it 10.5v, so the input voltage problem is solved i think, now regarding the power provided to the op-amp rails, i don't have a bipolar supply with a ground between them, i can only work a regular battery ( is there a way to make into one? ), i don't have to ground the non-inv. input, its just a thing i did since i saw it a lot before.

i ran out of char., so now might i use a +/-15v or a +/-18v battery to power the op-amp without the need of a ground between them? but if so then where do i put the non-inv. input, ( excuse my ignorance on the topic, electronics isn't my speciality, iam just taking a course in it, thank you in advance )

@AbdullahAhmed If you use two batteries, the ground can be the connection between them: {+ve rail} [+ BAT1 -] {gnd} [+ BAT2 -] {-ve rail}.

i did just that, and connected the non inv. to the ground, didn't work.

+/- 10 is recommended minimum. They will "probably" work down to when the Vcm in window closes. Vcn is withing 2V of supply typ and 3V max at 15V. Some suggest these values drop at lower V supplies. But 6V to be safe with zero headroom so 3 to 5V range at 9V supply. Maybe :-).Fig 9 here useful https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/1163/LM741.pdf

@AbdullahAhmed  As a learning exercise, now that you know what was needed, look at this answer again. It was posted before my answer and well before my update It contains the same basic information as mine - mainly about the circuit needing to operate within a band 2 or 3 vots away from either ower supply rail. My key point is that it helps to read answers slowly and carefully and understand the pouts being made. Even more so if answers are from people with very high reputation scores (such as Spehro has) as this shows that people generally find that their answers are usually very useful.

The issue is that the positive input is connected to ground. If you do that, the op-amp cannot work in an inverting amplifier circuit.

unfortunately same result without it connected to ground

@AbdullahAhmed I don't know what you did to it, but it was the problem. You might have still connected it incorrectly instead of correctly.

what do you suggest i connect it to? i left it open

@AbdullahAhmed It needs to be biased properly. Connecting it to ground or leaving it open are not correct. Are you familiar how single-supply inverting amplifiers should be biased?

yeah, i took it in my electronics course, they connected it to ground most if not all the time.

@AbdullahAhmed But not when supplied with single supply.

it actually was a single supply, but i might be missing something in this regard since the circuit isn't working, i will do more research on the topic and will try and bias it correctly, if you have any article, tutorial or reference that you think might be of use to me then please, kindly tell me about it, thank you for taking so much of your time debugging the problem, much appreciated really.

This complements other answers:
Others have suggested an opamp change to 'single supply'.
A venerable not quite as old LM324 (quad) / LM358 (dual) opamp is electrically similar to the 741 but single supply capable and will almost certainly meet your need.
Create a "reference ground" with a resistive divider.
You can use eg a 22k:10k divider from supply to ground and use one LM324 section as a unity gain buffer to provide an about 1/3 supply reference.
Note the LM324's common mode range - it will not tolerate V+ inputs and output is "almost rail to rail". When use with a reference voltage as above it functions well in most basic applications.

Added:
The LM741 was a brilliant opamp when it was introduced 56 years ago in 1968. Its day has long long long gone.
For an LM741 Vsupply is recommended to be +/- 10 V - ie 20V total.
A 9V supply will "probably" work if common mode input voltages are observed. Input voltages must not come closer than 2V from either supply (typical) or 3V (worst case).  So with a 9V supply (+9V, 0V) the input voltage can range from 0+3 to 9-3 = 3V to 6V.
Maybe 2V to 7V if you are feeling lucky.
See fig 14 on page 14 of the LM741 datasheet.
To achieve operation your working "ground" should be at 4.5V if you want a symmetrical maximum voltage swing of +/- 1.5V worst case or +/- 2.5V on a good day downhill with the wind behind you.
In your case if you MUST use an LM741, connect your ground point to a 4.5V reference voltage - either a resistor divider or better a divider buffered by an opamp.
LM324s are more avaiable, lower price, better performance.
You can buy anLM324 quad opamp in Egypt for 11 EGP here.
Or a dual LM358 in an 8 pinn DIP package for the same price here.
They sell a single LM741 for the same price.
LM741 datasheet

can't use the LM324, iam only allowed to use LM741.

@AbdullahAhmed Please kindly read the comment added to the question. You will keep receiving suggestions and reacting with "I can't do this" if you present this as "a project you have to do", without presenting the requirements and constraints. This could work in a forum, but not in a Q&A site.

@Russell McMahon, i can't thank you enough, you even provided me with a store link to buy it from in Egypt !!!!!!!! this world doesn't deserve you, really, thank you from the bottom of my heart, hope you, and your wife and kids have WONDERFUL life full of happiness and comfort, i will pray for you today, may Allah bless your heart brother, hope i become as devoted to my field just like your devotion to yours.

@AbdullahAhmed pleased to help. I've been to 35 countries but none in Africa, sadly. I may just possibly get to Africa next year - I'm designing some items aimed at refugee camp use. I've added a technical comment on your answer.

@RussellMcMahon dude is an angel!! hope your designed items help tons of people and iam sure they will, maybe when you come to Africa consider visiting Egypt and i'll be your free guide ( car rides included haha, joking, we ride camels not cars ), i hear we have some interesting stones laid in a certain way in the middle of the desert ( believe it on not i have never visited them in my life even though i live near them :( haha ), offer is real though, when you want to come even if after 5 years from now just comment here when you want to and i'll be there for you to thank you properly, cheers.

If you reconsider the decision to make the second waveform using an integrator, you may design a circuit to do just that. It is also an opportunity for you the check an option on how to produce a reference at an intermediary voltage between the power supply rails:

Since G1 and G2 are connected only to opamp inputs, the voltage dividers form a simple solution.

i can't consider this unfortunately since iam working on little space, however you are right about the learning opportunity indeed, i will work on it on my own after i hand over this project, thank you, much appreciated really.

No problem. But the voltage divider addresses your question about the reference. Note that opamps are not powered by GND in split power supply configuration. It is just a solid voltage reference for the circuit around the opamp.

I SOLVED IT!!!!, I am going to explain it in detail to make the old me understand, hope this helps someone in the future.
The problem was in the op-amp connection ( the non-inv., +Vcc and -Vcc ). I only had one battery to power it, making a +9v at the +Vcc and  ZERO at the -Vcc. Due to restrictions that I can only use batteries, I connected the +Vcc to the +9V terminal of the battery ( note: the -ve terminal of the battery is connected to the ground ), then brought another battery and connected the -Vcc to the negative terminal of the 2nd battery and connected the +ve terminal to the same ground previously mentioned. This made a bipolar power +/- 9V power supply, with the ground point of the supply being the ground previously mentioned.
Then I connected the non.inv terminal to the ground, AND VOILA... .
The last thing to mention is that if this doesn't work for YOU reading this, from the info. those heros from the answer section provided me, you need at least +/-10V at the +Vcc and -Vcc to make it work, I am just throwing this out there even though 9V worked fine with me, so yeah, hope that helps and a BIG THANK YOU to all the guys who answered me ( especially Eng.@Russell McMahon ) and devoted much of their - precious, I am sure - time to help a dude they don't know online out, really, thank you, hope you guys find more happiness in life.

You are correct - Your dual battery arrangement is what was needed! Note that as the batteries discharge the voltage will reduce. A 9V Alkaline cell operates down to about 6V so you would still have +/- 6V supplies. That should still work. See the datsheet reference in my answer. While +/- 10V is shown in the datasheet as the typical recommended voltages, fig 14 on page 14 of the 741 datasheet show you can use lower voltages BUT the available working range is 2 to 3 volts inside either supply.

I edited your answer. I added capitalisation of eg i and similar and added a few paragraph breaks. You may find it useful to compare what I have done compared with the original as a possible guide. There are many ways to write in English and your original was fully understandable. (I am 100% illiterate in Masri, al-fuṣḥā and Coptic :-) ). || It is usual not to include thanks in answers. It's likely that someone will edit this out at some stage but I felt that it would be ungrateful for me to do so :-). Thanks for your thanks to all the ones who helped.

certainly, i will compare it!, and regarding the thanks segment, i noticed that people here don't usually write it, but i can not go on with my life without thanking you, you guys help dudes you don't online without any holding back on info., and in my future posts to come i will thank the ones that would help me, i would feel guilty without it haha.

Site rules do not allow this in answers or question proper so someone will probably edit such material out in due course. It's acceptable in comments. It can feel sad but it's how the system works. This may feel mean but the object of the site is to provide searchable high value question and answer sets that cover the technical material and not to be generally chatty as may be the case in the forum. This can result in answers being to some extensive personalized but it does mean long-term the material is valuable to a wide range of people and is on the topic that they have searched for.
